# Issues with MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

So I was getting some problems with connecting .NET and MySQL and figured there was something wrong with the connector. Went into my control panel -> uninstall/repair -> repair MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3.

The repair starts normally but after a few seconds I get a screen saying "A serious problem occured during the installation". I tried reinstalling it but just got to the MySQL installer and it said all my products are up to date.

Now I went into the MySQL installer again to uninstall the .Net connector and got the error:

```
Removing system registry values
UnregisterPerfCounterData
RollbackUnregisterPerfCounterData
Unpublishing Product Features
Unpublishing assembly information
Updating component registration
InstallInitialize
1: MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3 2: {"SERIAL-CODE"} 3: 3 
The product Connector/NET failed to remove successfully.
```

I have repaired all the Visual Studio products without any problems except this one that is really vital for my project.

So now I am not sure what I should do...

Comment: Maybe try and run a progran like CCleaner, you might need some registry issues fixed. https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a program like CCleaner to remove all the traces of the program on the computer then download it again and it worked!